# What is the correct chronology in Sword Art Online what light novel and manga volumes?

Tags: sword-art-online

There are manga and light novels in Sword art online with three simultaneous separate series.  What is the way to chronologically read this series?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manga is just an adaptation of the Light Novels, so it follows the arcs in the original LN.

1. Aincrad
2. Fairy Dance
3. Phantom Bullet
4. Caliber
5. Mother's Rosario
6. Alicization

The Girl Ops manga can be read at any point after the Fairy Dance arc, as it's just a side-story.

Progressive is a reboot of sorts of the Aincrad arc, exploring from the first floor onwards, so it can be read on its own whenever you want.

Comment: This is not correct in that Mother's Rosario was never a name for an arc. Mother's Rosary is correct and is corroborated with the the publisher, Wikipedia, isbn, Amazon, and every dated and referenced authorities that have super control of any type of modifications to this format.